# android list and copy files from assets folder to app data

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I added some files to my android app inside folder "testFiles". I also created (at first launch) an empty folder with same name at data/data/... Next step should be listing files contained at assets "testFiles" and then copy all of them to new created folder at app data. I am doing same issue on iOS with following function, please note that objectiveC code is posted only to clarify what is asked. Thank you.

```
- (void)copyResources:(NSString *)sourcePath: (NSString *)destPath {

    NSArray* resContents = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    resContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];

    for (NSString* obj in resContents){
        NSError* error;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj] toPath:[destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj]
              error:&error])
            NSLog(@"Error en creació de directori: %@", error);;
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question.

Comment: My question is which function is used to list all files contained in a folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with assets, you use [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). To list the assets with a given prefix (e.g., folder name), use the `list()` method on `AssetManager`.